# Запись в БД добавляется, но не сохраняется

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Есть некий датагрид, с которым соединена база данных.
При запуске программы и нажатии кнопки *"Добавить"*, он успешно добавляет данные в таблицу и после обновления показывает мои новые добавленные данные. Но стоит мне закрыть программу, и заново ее запустить, как моих добавленных ранее данных - нет. Я так понимаю, программа добавляет их в базу данных, но до тех пор, пока работает программа и после ее выключения данные не сохраняются.  В интернете все написано на *SQL* и ответа найти не смог. Т.к это *c#* на Visual Studio, а там, походу, то ли не любят визуал, то ли не слышали то ли еще что-то.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    // this.tableTableAdapter.Update(test_0DataSet3);
    try
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();//разрешил изменения
        this.tableTableAdapter.Update(this.test_0DataSet3.Table);
        MessageBox.Show("Данные oбновлены!");
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка обновления!");
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Есть второй код добавления в таблицу, он на sql, но тоже не работает.
Тут я использовал TextBox, но это не важно, оно также добавляет данные в БД до тех пор, пока я не выключу программу, затем она не сохраняет данные. 
Код скопирован у другого задавшего вопрос человека этого сайта и попробован сделать собственноручно. В интернете все перерыл. Нет нормального кода который соответствовал бы тому, что мне нужно. Мне бы 1 раз точно понять, как это все делается, чтобы дальше не было вопросов. Я не прошу объяснять мне код, я это и так немного понимаю. И документацию могу прочитать в дальнейшем. Но мне нужно чтоб оно 100% работало, а логику написанного попытаюсь понять. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
{ 
  con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test_0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
  con.Open();

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  if (recordsAffected == 0)
  { 
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([Id], [Test1]) VALUES (@Id, @name)";
      // Добавить параметры
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 654);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);//Выполнить
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: маленькое замечание `using` автоматом закрывает подключение, не надо внутри него вызывать `Close()`

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой очень давно. Проблема была в том, что Conection указывал на БД, которая лежала в папке с проектом. Она то ли каждый раз синхронизировало ее с той базой, которую мы указываем при добавлении соединения, то ли это проблемы с настройкой самой базы. Попробуйте в ConnectionString указать полный путь к базе, к которой вы изначально подключались.

Еще помогал способ создания подключения не к БД, а к самому MSSQLSERVER (Имеется в виду сервер, где будет Ваша БД) в Visual Studio.